# Node.js setImmediate Idle Handlers

Tags: node.js, event-loop, libuv

In this talk the presenter suggests that setImmediate gets added to both the check phase and the idle phase so that setImmediate can force the system not to watch for I/O. This seems to chime with what I've seen the system do.

But what does it mean for the setImmediate to be added to idle handler? Does it potentially mean it gets run twice? I've run code like:

```
 const https = require('https');


function doRequest() {
  https.request('https://www.google.com', res => {
    res.on('data', () => {});
    res.on('end', () => {
      setImmediate(() => {
        console.log('hey');
      })
    })
  }).end();
}

doRequest();
```

Which outputs the SetImmediate callback twice. Is this related to the callback being set in two queues or something else? What does get put into the idle handler queue?

Comment: An individual `setImmediate()` callback does not get run twice unless you call `setImmediate()` twice.  Check and idle means that `setImmediate()` can be triggered in either of those phases, not that a single handler will be called twice.

Comment: When I run your code in node.js, I only see one output of `hey`.